# React Native Firebase, equalTo() is being aplied wrong?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have this database:

```
{
  "interpreters" : [ null, {
    "InterpreterID" : "1",
    "Name" : "Pedro",
    "languages" : [ "portuguese", "russian", "english", "german" ],
    "latitude" : 37.633,
    "latitudeDelta" : 0.0143,
    "longitude" : -122.345,
    "longitudeDelta" : 0.0134
  }, {
    "InterpreterID" : "2",
    "Name" : "Paulo",
    "languages" : [ "english", "portuguese" ],
    "latitude" : 37.554,
    "latitudeDelta" : 0.0143,
    "longitude" : -122.245,
    "longitudeDelta" : 0.0134
  } ]
}
```

And I'm trying to get only interpreters that match with the language I want. For example, get only interpreters
that speak russian.

I'm doing like this:

```
database()
      .ref()
      .child('interpreters')
      .orderByChild('languages')
      .equalTo('russian')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        setInterpreters(snapshot.val())
        console.log(snapshot.val())
      });
```

But it returns 'null'.

If I look for orderByChild('Name').equalTo('Pedro') then return Pedros data.

Maybe it's because languages is an array but I'm not sure how to get data from it and couldn't find how to do it.

The forEach method simple didn’t work without any error. The code ran fine but I couldn’t display anything.

I'm following firebase documentation and seems that there is nothing different.

What should I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't natively support arrays, well it does in form of objects. An array that you send as

```
["Portuguese", "Russian"]
```

is converted to

```
{0: "Portuguese", 1: "Russian"}
```

Hence your queries don't work as expected. **Firebase doesn't support querying inner values of arrays**

### The workaround

Firebase recommends changing your data to:

```
{
  "portugese": true,
  "russian": true
}
```

and then query as

```
.orderByChild('languages/portuguese')
.equalTo(true)
```

Comment: Oooh, I see. This answers all. Thank you very much !!